# How to read in only a particular number of characters

Tags: c++, c

I have a small query regarding reading a set of characters from a structure. For example: A particular variable contains a value "3242C976*32" (char - type). How can I get only the first 8 bits of this variable. Kindly help.

Thanks.

Edit:
I'm trying to read in a signal:

For Ex: $ASWEER,2,X:3242C976*32

into this structure:

```
struct pg
    {
        char command[7];  // saves as $ASWEER,2,X:3242C976*32
        char comma1[1];  // saves as ,2,X:3242C976*32
        char groupID[1]; // saves as 2,X:3242C976*32
        char comma2[1]; // etc
        char handle[2]; // this is the problem, need it to save specifically each part, buts its not
        char canID[8];
        char checksum[3];
    }m_pg;
```

...
When memcopying buffer into a structure, it works but because there is no carriage returns it saves the rest of the signal in each char variable. So, there is always garbage at the end.

Comment: Is this C or C++? And how comes MFC into play?

Comment: 8 "bits"? Or did you mean the first eight "characters"?

Comment: Assumming `8` chars, why don't you read it one char at a time in a loop?

Comment: Yes, the first 8 characters. Like I just need to be able to read 3242C976 and chuck the rest of the characters. But every time I do that, it reads the whole thing. (I think it reads till a carriage return is reached).

Comment: -1 for not posting the code you've written.

Comment: what do you mean by "read"? what is the operation -- expressed in C++ code -- that you are performing for a "read" ?

Comment: C and C++ are not the same; though similar, a solution for one of them (likely) may not work for the other.

Comment: -1 & voting for close: Because I am tired of users not answering questions regarding their toolset/setup.

Comment: Oh, yeah sorry about that. I was really engrossed in getting the solution and did not look at all the comments added. This question was regarding C,C++ and I was programming in MFC Dialog Based application using Visual Studio .Net 2003.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could..
convert your hex value in canID to float(depending on how you want to display it), e.g.

```
float value1 = HexToFloat(m_pg.canID); // find a conversion script for HexToFloat

CString val;
val.Format("0.3f",value1);
```

the garbage values aren't actually being stored in the structure, it only displays it as so, as there is no carriage return, so format the message however you want to and display it using the `CString val;`

Answer (score 2):

If "3242C976*3F" is a c-string or std::string, you can just do:

```
char* str = "3242C976*3F";
char first_byte = str[0];
```

Or with an arbitrary memory block you can do:

```
SomeStruct memoryBlock;
char firstByte;
memcpy(&firstByte, &memoryBlock, 1);
```

Both copy the first 8bits or 1 byte from the string or arbitrary memory block just as well.

Comment: Somebody has been assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8`... :-)

Comment: Haha, yeah, yeah - I'll concede to that :)

Answer (score 2):

After the edit (original answer below)

Just copy by parts. In C, something like this should work (could also work in C++ but may not be idiomatic)

```
strncpy(m_pg.command, value, 7); // m.pg_command[7] = 0; // oops
strncpy(m_pg.comma, value+7, 1); // m.pg_comma[1] = 0; // oops
strncpy(m_pg.groupID, value+8, 1); // m.pg_groupID[1] = 0; // oops
strncpy(m_pg.comma2, value+9, 1); // m.pg_comma2[1] = 0; // oops
// etc
```

Also, you don't have space for the string terminator in the members of the structure (therefore the oopses above). They **are NOT strings**. Do not `printf` them!

---

Don't read more than 8 characters. In C, something like

```
char value[9]; /* 8 characters and a 0 terminator */
int ch;
scanf("%8s", value);

/* optionally ignore further input */
while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF)) /* void */;
/* input terminated with ch (either '\n' or EOF) */
```

I believe the above code also "works" in C++, but it may not be idiomatic in that language

Comment: Both of them do not work for my program as we do not have a "\n" or EOF in our case. We just need to be able to read the canID part and ignore the checksum. But it displays both somehow.

Comment: @Nerds.Dont.Swear: you.need.the.zero.terminator.for.strings otherwise.they.are.not.strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a char pointer, you can just set `str[8] = '\0';`  Be careful though, because if the buffer is less than 8 (EDIT: **9**) bytes, this could cause problems.

(I'm just assuming that the name of the variable that already is holding the string is called `str`. Substitute the name of your variable.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you want to split at the comma, and save up to there.  This can be done with strtok(), to split the string into tokens based on the comma, or strchr() to find the comma, and strcpy() to copy the string up to the comma.